# What embedded database to use for seamless MySQL > (embedded database) dumping

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hsqldb, spring-test

What embedded database can I use that has SQL syntax thats the same as MySQL? I ask cause I've been struggling with HSQLDB the mismatch between it and MySql SQL syntaxes makes it difficult for me to create a dump of MySQL database (production) and import that dump to HSQLDB for testing.

PS. I am using Spring test, hibernate and hsqldb at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No other database has exactly the same syntax as MySQL. The next version of HSQLDB (2.3.3) has a more extensive MySQL syntax compatibility mode. This includes creation of indexes inside CREATE TABLE statements, INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE ROW UPDATE ... syntax and more.

But if you still have a problem converting, there are several data conversion tools that allow you to import the data into HSQLDB. See some links here: http://hsqldb.org/web/hsqlUsing.html

Comment: I was afraid this was the case, thank you @fredt but my real problem was that i can't take MYSQL inserts and run them on HSQLDB without some editing, i thought I could find a DB that can do that

Comment: You can always report an example of the inserts than need editing.

Comment: TINYINT(3) on a create for example fails and is a valid MySQL statement